# Using java Scanner class

Tags: java.util.scanner

I am trying to get user inputs(integers) till she enters 'end'(String). I am trying the following code, but its storing only alternate numbers entered in the array. Please suggest.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);                
        List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        System.out.println("Enter 'end' to stop input");                
        while(!sc.next().equals("end")){                    
            if(sc.hasNextInt()){            
                al.add(Integer.valueOf(sc.nextInt()));
            }           
        }
        sc.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a "homework" question.

When you call `sc.next()` you are *consuming* a token.  That's why you are only seeing half of the numbers.

The logic of the key part your program needs to be like this:

```
  is the next token an integer?
      yes - read it as an integer
      no - read it as a string, test if it is "end" and decide what to do next
```

Comment: thanks for replying. But the above logic will work for one iteration(if statement). How to make it iterative(like using while)? Could you post a snippet.Thanks!